# How to use font-awesome icon inside <option>

Tags: php, font-awesome

I was trying to insert fontawsome Gender Icons inside option tag and change the color of the icons, I tried all the possible suggestion on the net but I am not able to figure it out.
here is the code

```
function listGender($sex){
    global $lang;
    $list = '';
    $list .= '<option ' . selCurrent($sex, 1) . ' value="1">' . $lang['male'] . '</option>';
    $list .= '<option ' . selCurrent($sex, 2) . ' value="2">' . $lang['female'] . '</option>';
    $list .= '<option ' . selCurrent($sex, 3) . ' value="3">' . $lang['other'] . '</option>';
    return $list;
}
```

can someone guide me please.

Comment: What exactly is not working with this code? I see nothing related to Fontawesome here

Comment: Corrected typos, added font-awsome tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside <**option**> tag you can't use <**i**> tag, so in this case you have to use uni-code of fa icons(given at [font awesome website](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/female)).

You have to mention font familty of <**option**> as **FontAwesome** and then provide unicode as below:

```
<option style=" font-family: 'FontAwesome';" value="male">&#xf183;</option>
```

For Full code, you may run below html and check:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<select>
    <option  value="left">Select</option>
    <option style=" font-family: 'FontAwesome';" value="male">&#xf183;</option>
    <option style=" font-family: 'FontAwesome';" value="female">&#xf182;</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```